# List difference between 2 columns excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns looking like this:

```
A    |    B
-----|------
a    |    a
b    |    c
c    |    e
d    |    g
e    |    i
f    |    k
g    |    l
```

And I am looking for an array formula to list all the elements from A that are not in B:

```
C
--
b
d
f
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in columns **A** and **B** like:

[image]

In **C2** enter the *array formula*:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A11,B2:B11,0)),A2:A11,"")
```

and copy down.  Then in **D2** enter the *array formula*:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW(D$2:D$11)+1>ROWS(C$2:C$11)-COUNTBLANK(C$2:C$11),"",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL((IF(C$2:C$11<>"",ROW(C$2:C$11),ROW()+ROWS(C$2:C$11))),ROW()-ROW(D$2:D$11)+1),COLUMN(C$2:C$11),4)))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Column **C** extracts those items from column **A** that are missing in column **B**. 
 Column **D** simply squeezes the blanks out of column **C**.

*(Based on [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/noblanks.aspx)*)